# python support in gvim but not console vim

Tags: python, bash, vim

Windows 7 - 
I'm a fairly new Windows person and am trying to get a nice setup with Vim, Ultisnips, and more in the console. To get Ultisnips working, it appears I need python support in Vim. I have installed Python 2.7.9 (and other later versions) and reinstalled Vim74 multiple times, but python shows as -python, -python3 in vim's version report.
Now GVim does show python support, but running vim from git bash does not. See screenshot.
In GVim, when I do :python import sys; print(sys.version), it shows
2.7.9 (default, Dec 10... etc) Is it reflecting the preferred Python it needs, or just what I have installed?

I would love to use vim in the console/terminal with Ultisnips.
Do I have to install Vim in a special way? Or set something in _vimrc? The console vim also doesn't display :help either (gvim is fine), but that's another issue (related?)
I have spent a good chunk of time looking at relevant articles, but can't get it to work. Thanks for any advice!

[python config screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mllqe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console vim command was apparently running a copy of vim in the Git directory, where it seems to be missing a bunch of things including /doc, hence the 'help' not working. I can now run vim in the program files directory via console, where it now shows python support, and help etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put settings in `.gvimrc/_gvimrc` beside the `.vimrc/_vimrc` file.

For the help about `gvimrc` type `:h gvimrc` when in command mode in `vim`.

If the gvimrc files exist, they are used to configure Vim when the GUI version (gvim) runs (after settings from vimrc are applied).

Settings for gvim can *also* be placed in the vimrc file using a has('gui_running') check:

```
if has('gui_running')
  set guioptions-=T  " no toolbar
  colorscheme elflord
endif
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm actually aiming to use Vim in the console, not GVim. So setting things in gvimrc probably won't help me here.